# print the sum of a block (array) in runtime mips given an continue input

Tags: sum, mips

i'm gonna explain my problem simply as possible:

-user have to input a number (K)

-than he have to input while input is !=0  integers (so a sequence)

for example:

1,2,**3,4,5**,6  , 0

if k = 3

program will sum all group o k elements (see stronger number in the sequence)

output so will be:  6, 9, 12, 15

i tried to coding that and that's the result:

```
    .globl main


.data
.eqv $K, $a1
.eqv $S, $t1
.text



main:
    li $v0, 5
    syscall 
    move $K, $v0

    move $t0, $zero
#carico vettore 
for:
    beq $t0, $K, stampa_somma
    li $v0, 5
    syscall #eseguo la somma una volta messo in input l elemento
    beqz $v0, end
    subi $sp, $sp, 4
    sw $v0, ($sp)
    beqz $t0, memorizza
    add $S, $S, $v0
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    j for

memorizza:
    move $t2, $sp #memorizzo il valore iniziale
    add $S, $S, $v0
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    j for
stampa_somma:
    move $a0, $S #stampo la somma
    li $v0,1
    syscall 
    li  $a0, '\n'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    seq $t0, $t0, 0
    move $sp, $t2
    j shift

shift: 
    beq $t0,$K, fine_shift
    lw $t3, ($sp)
    addi $sp,$sp, 4
    sw $t3, ($sp)
    subi $sp, $sp, 8
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    j shift

fine_shift:
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    li $v0, 5
    syscall 
    beqz $v0, end
    sw $v0, ($sp)

    move $sp, $t2
    seq $t0, $t0,0
    seq $S, $S, 0
    j somma

somma:
    beq $t0, $K, stampa_somma
    lw $a3, ($sp)
    add $S, $S, $a3
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    subi $sp,$sp, 4
    j somma


end: 
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

with simply numbers programm works, but with high K and high numbers there is a differences between the last output integers, what's wrong with my code?thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here. Wouldn't `for (int i = 0; arr[i+K-1] != 0; i++) { int sum = 0; for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) { sum += arr[i + j]; } }` do the job? Translating that into MIPS assembly should be very straight-forward.

Comment: nope mate, that's the point , because i don't create a static array first, ( so your "arr" is not already decleared and it doesn' t have any elements when your first for starts

Comment: The fact that you're storing the numbers on the stack doesn't really make it any more complicated. It just changes the order of traversal. Alternatively, since you know K before you start reading the values, you could allocate memory on the heap using syscall 9 and store the values there in the normal order instead of using the stack.